# Create a function to check that col1 and col2 do not have the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

So far I tried this:

```
 Create function dbo.Checkname(@Firstn varchar(20), @secondn  varchar(20))
 Return varchar
 as
 begin 
     Declare @Firstn as FirstName
        Union all
         @secondn as Secondname
```

Or I have to use where statement

```
where (col1 <> col2)
```

Comment: Why do you need function when you can use WHERE as you defined in the question?

Comment: As @dotnetom said, you can check in your query by using WHERE statement. You don't need additional function call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using oracle:

```
create or replace function diff(value1 type, value2 type) return integer is
   begin
     if (value1 <> value2) then
        return 0;
     else
        return 1;
     -- exceptions
   end;
```

Comment: Why even create such function? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Maybe he's following a tutorial os something ... But i don't see any use in something like this.